# How do you setup an affiliate program for your Xamarin Forms App?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, xamarin.ios

I want to setup an affiliate program for my app where affiliate marketers can share an Affiliate Link. The link should bring a user to the iOS AppStore or Android Playstore to install my App. The App can then be attributed to the marketer, so that if there are any purchases, the marketer will get a cut.

Can someone point me in the right direction how to achieve this?

Is there such a Xamarin Library that can help me achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: there is no way to determine which link a user followed to install your app from the store

Comment: You can achieve this two different ways, deep links (they are preserved across the install process if the user does not have already, plenty of tutorials out there for this process), or you use the native OSs referrer system, i.e. Google has the "Play Install Referrer Library" that can be used to pull the "referring" URL from the user's Play Store account

Comment: Thank you Sushi, which of the two method is better/easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this is using a "contextual" deep linking tool/sdk/library, because in the case of iOS, there's no other way of retaining the "context" of the link. Here's a [short blog](https://blog.branch.io/in-deeplinking-context-matters/) explanation describing the differences between the basic and contextual deep links, and this is an image:
[image: Contextual Deep Linking explanation]

The most reliable solution I have seen and used is [branch.io](https://branch.io), but I have heard some people having success with Firebase's Deeplinks.

Branch is [open source](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/xamarin-branch-deep-linking-attribution) and has updated [Nuget Packages](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Branch-Xamarin-Linking-SDK) and really [good documentation](https://help.branch.io/developers-hub/docs/xamarin-android)